# Unable to download files : I am using anchor tag to download file but the localhost is appended to it and the link is jumbled up

Tags: html, anchor

```
<a target="_blank" href=`{{url}}` download>Download {{body}}</a>
```

This is the code I am using.

href link should be `https://matrix-client.matrix.org/_matrix/media/r00/download/matrix.org/dsgakdgaksgd`

wrong href link is `http://localhost:3000/%60https://matrix-client.matrix.org/_matrix/media/r00/download/matrix.org/dsgakdgaksgd%60`

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: It depends on the `url` value. Is it an absolute URL, or a relative URL?

Comment: It's a absolute URL, meanwhile when i used the `href="https://matrix-client.matrix.org/_matrix/media/r00/download/matrix.org/{{changingPart}}"` instead of the `{{url}}` it worked (means no localhost part was attached to it)

Comment: If it's really an absolute URL, the URL shouldn't be changed to localhost unless you have other logics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`href="https://matrix-client.matrix.org/_matrix/media/r00/download/matrix.org/{{changingPart}}"`
```

I used the above URL instead of the {{url}} it worked and there was  no localhost part was attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect the user to an absolute path, the HTML anchor tag should contain the following properties.

```
<a href="https://matrix-client.matrix.org/_matrix/media/r00/download/matrix.org/dsgakdgaksgd" target="_blank" download>Download {{body}}</a>
```